# php get function not inserting data into the textbox?

Tags: php, html, textarea

i have this textarea, that takes the value of a get function transferred from another page,

```
<textarea name="inputField" value="<?php echo $_GET['replyto'];?>" id="inputField" tabindex="1" rows="2" cols="40"onblur="DoBlur(this);" onfocus="DoFocus(this);" ></textarea>
```

this is the url link,

```
http://localhost/final/home.php?replyto=@sam&status_id=2&reply_name=sam
```

its not inserting @sam in the textbox,
is thier something wrong?

Comment: We can't access a link to http://localhost/ =) That's your own personal computer. You have to put the script somewhere that's accessible from the web. Or if your personal computer is accessible from the web, you have to supply us with your IP address or a domain name that points to it.

Comment: the url is just for illustration, thats why i didnt make it linkable!!!

Comment: Just an advise: as a matter of fact, your question has nothing to do with PHP and "get function". Just make your code in clean HTML and get the same result. That's why **you should always check HTML source of the page**, not an image rendered by the browser.

Comment: thanks for the advice, sorry about that @col

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of a `<textarea>` don't go into the "value" parameter, they go between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`. Try this:

```
<textarea name="inputField" id="inputField" tabindex="1" rows="2" cols="40"onblur="DoBlur(this);" onfocus="DoFocus(this);" >
<?php echo $_GET['replyto'];?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks that works, but it deosnt focus on the textarea, do you know how i can achieve this! by the way im accepting your answer ;)) cheers again +1 vote

Comment: If you want to set focus when the page loads, you needs to just use the Javascript `focus()` function. So for instance, if your `<textarea>` was a member of `<form name="theForm">`, you would want to add the following to your `<body>` tag: `<body onload="document.theForm.inputArea.focus();">`